# Array to string in TCL

Tags: scripting, tcl

How can I convert a known array in to string in TCL? an array might have values such as `root_user_appversion 10.1.3.20` and/or I just want to take out the last values out of it which `10.1.3.20` .

Comment: At least show your effort what you have done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can transform the array in list:

```
set my_list [array get my_array]

puts "last element: [lindex $my_list [expr {[llength $my_list] -1}] ]"
```

After that, you can easily convert your list in string with `join`:

```
set my_string [join $my_list " "]
```

Comment: `lindex $my_list end` is more idiomatic.

Comment: Another problem with this is that it doesn't really solve the problem, it just stringifies the array contents.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
join [dict values [array get the_array]]
```

Which takes a list of alternating key / value items, filters out the value items, and joins them into a string.

Note that values with spaces will be munged: in that case you're better off with just `dict values [array get the_array]`.

Documentation: [array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm), [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm)