# can't read "env": variable is array

Tags: tcl

I got the following error from the TCL interpreter when trying to get the value of `env` variable:

```
puts $env
can't read "env": variable is array
```

How can get the value of a TCL variable if it is an array?

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36081328/array-to-string-in-tcl

Answer (score 2):

[`parray`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/parray) was introduced in Tcl8.5 and is used to 'puts' arrays:

```
parray env
```

Note that you need to provide the array name and not the array variable.

Otherwise, you can use a loop:

```
foreach {key value} [array get env] {
    puts "env($key) = $value"
}
```

Comment: I thought it was around long before that. I remember using it in Tcl 7.4...

Comment: @DonalFellows I just inferred that from the link in the wiki oops. I'm not really sure for how long it's been around, but if it's from 7.4, then I'm wrong there.

Comment: Plus [there are lots more `array` subcommands](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/array.htm). For example: `foreach key [array names env] {puts "env($key) = $env($key)"}`

Comment: According to the Tcl `changes` file (the only way to do code archaeology that far back quickly) it predates 6.5, as the changes for 6.5 document a behaviour *change* for it (probably a switch to using `upvar` instead of `global`) implying that it must've been there before and had users. It's all before my time going that far back...